# Why there is a AdobeAAMDetect plugin showing up in my Safari Preferences Windows?

Tags: macos, mac, safari, adobe-flash, plugins

I have never installed Adobe Flash Player on my Mac cause it has some dangerous security breaches and potentially harmful for your mac then how come this plugin is showing up in Safari, is my Mac hacked?

One more thing I have Creative Cloud installed on my Mac.

[image]

Comment: AAM is Adobe Application Manager - responsible for your CC account status/sync/licensing etc. No connection to Flash.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ok then why on enabling this plugin the sites which appears under it, for example: YouTube and I guess YouTube uses Flash so I thought this (AAM) might have some connection with Flash Player

Comment: YouTube hasn't used Flash by default in at least a year; it uses HTML5. Flash is dead, it just hasn't realised it yet ;-)

Comment: @Tetsujin Is it because of this that my subtitles icon is still stuck with the old layout of YouTube check out this screenshot to understand my comment better link: https://dbr.ee/iKjg

Comment: I have no idea. I doubt the two are even vaguely connected.